# How do I take this JSON data in PHP file and make it a variable?

Tags: php, json, api, jsondecoder

I am pulling a web API and want to take one of the values it gives me, a number, and assign it to a variable with no decimal points. I use XMLHttprequest to get the data and then get the individual value by

```
$JSON = file_get_contents("url.to.api.json");
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($JSON, TRUE)),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

   $character = json_decode($JSON);
print $character->cases/1000; // this gives me the right value, but I can't carry it to other parts of the app or round off the number, I can't figure out how to make it a variable.
```

I can print the value and divide it by a thousand, but I'm not sure how to make that value a variable and also how to remove decimal points and round down. If it gives me 500.05, I just want 500, and I want to be able to reuse this value.

This is my first time working with an API and JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just assign the value to a variable and then pass it around you codebase, in the following code snippet I assigned the value to a variable and used [floor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor) to round it down:

```
<?php

$JSON = file_get_contents("url.to.api.json");
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($JSON, TRUE)),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$character = json_decode($JSON);
$val = floor($character->cases/1000); // this gives me the right value, but I can't carry it to other parts of the app or round off the number, I can't figure out how to make it a variable.
echo $val;
```

Comment: That worked, I just had to put the bracket around to the end like this: val = floor($character->cases/1000);  to round. Thank you, greatly appreciated.

Comment: glad to help you!